# Extracting monthly dates from Dataframe time series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I'm using Python 2.7.13.

I have a Pandas Dataframe that contains business days as index and numerical data in each column.

I am trying to :

1/ Extract monthly dates from the Dataframe. I managed to get the End of month dates but I need to have dates that are part of the original set. For exemple, if the end of month is a sunday, i need to get the closest business day.

2/ Ideally, I am also looking for an elegent way to get a Dataframe that : has the same dates as index as the original Dataframe. For each column, the first value is equal to the value of the original Dataframe, then if the date is NOT a monthly date, the value is equal to the preceding value (of the new Dataframe), and if the date is a monthly date, the value is equal to the value of the same date from the original Dataframe.

I tried several solutions, such a merge asof (didn't work because keys must be sorted which i don't understand) or doing iteration testing distance between dates (didn't work because series not iterable)

Thanks for your help

Problem solved :

For those interested, I found a solution :

in order to creat the monthly date, I used a custom calendar :

```js
CustCal=pd.tseries.offsets.CustomBusinessDay(calendar=BT_Histos.index)

"""then I creat the date with : """

 RebalDates = pd.date_range(start=BTParams['EffectiveStartDate'], end=BTParams['EndDate'], freq=frequency)+ pd.tseries.offsets.Day(dayadd)+ 0*CustCal
```

Exemple :

```
Original                                    What i try to get       
            Col1    Col2    Col3                    Col1    Col2    Col3
15/02/2007  119.770 1.033   1.007       15/02/2007  119.770 1.033   1.007
16/02/2007  119.770 1.034   1.006       16/02/2007  119.770 1.033   1.007
20/02/2007  118.439 1.034   1.009       20/02/2007  119.770 1.033   1.007
21/02/2007  119.326 1.032   1.007       21/02/2007  119.770 1.033   1.007
22/02/2007  118.235 1.031   1.006       22/02/2007  119.770 1.033   1.007
23/02/2007  117.108 1.029   1.003       23/02/2007  119.770 1.033   1.007
26/02/2007  116.975 1.030   1.002       26/02/2007  119.770 1.033   1.007
27/02/2007  114.358 1.003   0.967       27/02/2007  119.770 1.033   1.007
28/02/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972       28/02/2007  119.770 1.033   1.007
01/03/2007  111.271 1.002   0.970       01/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
02/03/2007  110.197 0.997   0.959       02/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
05/03/2007  110.650 0.985   0.950       05/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
06/03/2007  111.847 0.996   0.964       06/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
07/03/2007  111.989 0.995   0.962       07/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
08/03/2007  113.826 1.002   0.969       08/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
09/03/2007  114.190 1.003   0.969       09/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
12/03/2007  112.672 1.004   0.972       12/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
13/03/2007  110.818 0.989   0.952       13/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
14/03/2007  106.480 0.989   0.959       14/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
15/03/2007  108.591 0.997   0.962       15/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
16/03/2007  107.474 0.997   0.958       16/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
19/03/2007  110.579 1.006   0.969       19/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
20/03/2007  111.989 1.011   0.975       20/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
21/03/2007  111.954 1.024   0.992       21/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
22/03/2007  114.864 1.024   0.991       22/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
23/03/2007  115.627 1.025   0.992       23/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
26/03/2007  113.977 1.023   0.993       26/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
27/03/2007  114.136 1.018   0.987       27/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
28/03/2007  112.770 1.012   0.979       28/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
29/03/2007  114.571 1.018   0.983       29/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
30/03/2007  114.775 1.021   0.982       30/03/2007  112.974 1.004   0.972
02/04/2007  113.781 1.022   0.984       02/04/2007  114.775 1.021   0.982
03/04/2007  115.316 1.031   0.994       03/04/2007  114.775 1.021   0.982
04/04/2007  115.582 1.032   0.995       04/04/2007  114.775 1.021   0.982
05/04/2007  116.629 1.034   0.998       05/04/2007  114.775 1.021   0.982
10/04/2007  118.421 1.037   1.001       10/04/2007  114.775 1.021   0.982
```

The 28/02/07 is a wednesday so it is valide monthly date. The values for the next business day (01/03/07) for the new dataframe are the values of the 28/02/07 of the original one. The 31/03/07 is a saturday so i take the 30/03/07 as monthly date. The value of the next business day (02/04/07) are the values of the 30/03/07.

Comment: Could you provide [mcve]?

Comment: Sure zipa. I modify my original question. Thx